# Is In app purchase sandboxtesting allowed once the app is in App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I just wanted to know that once the app is in App store and If I need to change some In App purchase code and test it. Is it allowed that I can use the test user account for Sandbox testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the test user account for Sandbox testing.

For this there is no need to upload binary.Make sure that status of InAppPurchase item must be "Ready to submit" not "Submit for review"(for sandbox testing only.) And then you project will be mapped to that app via App Bundle ID.

Comment: what if i  need to check for the current version of app?

Answer (score 1):

Ya sure, you can use the sandbox test user accounts. but you need to Add new version, then you can proceed with new sandbox testing.